# using break in JasperReports 4.7.0 vs 5.1.2

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

We are generating an *Excel* report from *Ext JS* UI which has a few filter parameters and a button to fetch the data as per the selected filters. The data is displayed in a *Ext JS* grid below the filter components. During the export of data, the filter parameters are to be put in the sheet 1 of *Excel* and the data to be put in the sheet 2. This works fine with *JasperReports* jar 4.7.0 but with *JR* jar 5.1.2, the filter details and the data are in the same sheet. Note that there is no code change and just the jar has changed.

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Below is the jrxml and a few lines of *Java* code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="REPORT TITLE" pageWidth="1400" pageHeight="800" columnWidth="1360" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" isIgnorePagination="true">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="851"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all" value="Filter Criteria/REPORT TITLE"/>
    <style name="table 2_CH" isDefault="true" mode="Opaque">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <paragraph leftIndent="2" rightIndent="2"/>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" isBold="true"/>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1">
        <parameter name="reportDataSrc" class="java.lang.Object">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[reportDataSrc]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <field name="xxx" class="java.lang.Object">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[xxx]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>

    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="reportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dataSrc" class="java.util.List">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[dataSrc]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Filter_Information" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Filter_Information]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="filterInformationSrc" class="java.util.List">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[filterInformationSrc]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="fileType" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[fileType]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="user" class="java.lang.Object">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[user]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band/>
    </title>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="10">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement style="table 3_CH" positionType="Float" x="765" y="0" width="120" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{fileType} != null && $P{fileType}.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["User : " + ($P{user})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="table 3_CH" positionType="Float" x="985" y="0" width="74" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{fileType} != null && $P{fileType}.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue())+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement style="table 3_CH" positionType="Float" x="1059" y="0" width="21" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{fileType} != null && $P{fileType}.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + ($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy h.mm a">
                <reportElement style="table 3_CH" positionType="Float" x="1180" y="0" width="120" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{fileType} != null && $P{fileType}.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF") )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{filterInformationSrc} != null && $P{filterInformationSrc}.size() > 0 )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="filterInformationSrc">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{filterInformationSrc}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[(new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{filterInformationSrc}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Filter_Information}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="1" width="100" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean($P{fileType} != null && $P{fileType}.equalsIgnoreCase("Excel") && $P{filterInformationSrc} != null && $P{filterInformationSrc}.size() > 0 )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="" style="table 2_CH" positionType="Float" x="0" y="6" width="1360" height="42" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1">
                        <datasetParameter name="reportDataSrc">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataSrc}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[(new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{dataSrc}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="151">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 2_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="151" height="25" backcolor="#99CCFF"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[xxx]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="151" height="25"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{xxx}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>                    
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Loading jrxml

```
JasperDesign jasperDesignObj = JRXmlLoader.load(ReportUtil.getJRXMLResourcePath(reportType, CommonConstants.JRXML_EXTENSION));
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataProviderList);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesignObj);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
```

The jasperPrint.getPages().size() returns 2 with 4.7.1 but 1 with 5.1.2, not sure how this happens.

Properties set:

```
if (CommonConstants.FILE_TYPE_EXCEL.equals(fileType)) {
    parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
    parameters.put(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
    parameters.put(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    parameters.put(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
    parameters.put(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: It is a repost of your today's post. It is a bad idea to repost the same question. You can improve the old one

Comment: I deteted it...not sure if its reflected yet..I feel this post explains the issue better..pls provide your suggestions and let me know if any further information is required...

Comment: What exporter did you use (JExcelApiExporter, JRXlsExporter or JRXlsxExporter)?

Comment: Sorry.....its the `JRXlsxExporter` and not JRXlsExporter